# Why Thomas Hardy set up his novels in cities of imaginary names?

Tags: thomas-hardy

Jude Fawley was living in Marygreen and went to Chirstminster, Christminster was a place of wisdom for him and due to some other details we infer that Hardy’s Chrisminster was intact Oxford.

Far From the Madding Crowd is set is Wessex, an imaginary city in Southwest England. The Mayor of Casterbridge is set in rural England named Casterbridge.

Why the fictional lands and their fictional names?